# Match all 'X' from 'Y' until 'Z'

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Well, I hope the title is not too confusing. My task is to match (and replace) all `X`s that are between `Y` and `Z`.

I use `X,Y,Z` since those values may vary at runtime, but that's not a problem at all.

What I've tried so far is this:

```
pattern = ".*Y.*?(X).*?Z.*";
```

Which actually works.. but only for one `X`. I simply can't figure out, how to match all `X`s between those "tags".

I also tried this:

```
pattern = @"((Y|\G).*?)(?!Z)(X)"
```

But this matches all `X`s, ignoring the "tags".

What is the correct pattern to solve my problem? Thanks in advance :)

## Edit

some more information:

`X` is a single `char`, `Y` and `Z` are `strings`

A more real life test string:

```
Some.text.with.dots [nodots]remove.dots.here[/nodots] again.with.dots
```

=> match `.`s between `[nodots]` and `[/nodots]`

(note: I used xml-like syntax here, but that's not guaranteed so I can *unfortunately* not use a simple xml or html parser)

Comment: I am afraid you need to provide a more real-life example string.

Comment: Clearly you tried `?(X*)`... or "X" means sequence of characters?

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/Tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cG%28%3f!%5e%29%7cy%28%3f%3d%5b%5ez%5d*z%29%29%5b%5ezx%5d*%28x%29&i=+gh+y+hh+x+x+x+z). All `x`s are in Group 1. Or [this one](http://regexstorm.net/Tester?p=y%28%3f%3a%5b%5ezx%5d*%28x%29%29*%5b%5ez%5d*z&i=+gh+y+hh+x+x+x+z).

Comment: I edited the question with a better example :)

Comment: Have a try [like this](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5bnodots%5c%5d%29%7c%5cG%28%3f!%5e%29%29%28%5b%5e.%5d*%3f%29%5c.%28%3f%3d.*%3f%5c%5b%2fnodots%5c%5d%29&i=Some.text.with.dots+%5bnodots%5dremove.dots.here%5b%2fnodots%5d+again.with.dots&r=%241) (replace with `$1`).

Comment: Awesome! it works just the way I need it. Why not post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Wait, you do not need that unreadable `\G` based regex if you have access to code. Do you? If yes, in C#, it can be done much easier.

Comment: Yes, I'm using C#

Comment: Then use my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, if you need to replace some text inside some block of text, you may match the block(s) with a simple regex like `(?s)(START)(.*?)(END)` and then inside a match evaluator make the necessary replacements in the matched blocks.

In your case, you may use something like

```
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?s)(\[nodots])(.*?)(\[/nodots])",
    m => string.Format(
        "{0}{1}{2}", 
            m.Groups[1].Value,                  // Restoring start delimiter
            m.Groups[2].Value.Replace(".",""),  // Modifying inner contents
            m.Groups[3].Value                   // Restoring end delimiter 
        )
    );
```

See the [C# online demo](http://ideone.com/quuo6L)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?s)` - an inline version of the `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier flag
- `(\[nodots])`- Group 1: starting delimiter (literal string `[nodots]`)
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `(\[/nodots])` - Group 3: end delimiter (literal string `[/nodots]`)